# The application cannot access the ios keychain for the application publisher (the teamid is null) only on iOS 14 and below

Tags: ios, xamarin, keychain, azure-ad-msal

I am getting error while initializing PublicClientApplicationBuilder. I have uploaded application on company portal. It is working fine on iOS 15 but not working on iOS 14.7 and below.

```
pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
         .Create(ADALConstants.ClientId)
         .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup("com.microsoft.adalcache")
         .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUri)
         .WithAuthority(ADALConstants.Authority)
         .WithBroker()
         .Build();
```

I have added custom Entitlements.plist and it has below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also, I have checked if Entitlements.plist is selected in iOS Bundle Signing. I am using Microsoft.Identity.Client (4.36.2)

Its weird as it is working fine on iOS 15 but giving error on other versions.

Note: In debug mode it is working on iOS 14.7 and below.

Comment: Are you using visual-studio for mac? When did the error occur？

Comment: @WenxuLi-MSFT  Yes, I am using Visual-Studio for mac. It occurs at the time of `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` initialization.